# AS web navigation

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm a web designer. In a effort to make Flash-based sites for my clients I have gone over stacks of AS books now for months. I just don't get any of it--and I've tried. Moreover, the books all give abstract examples to do just about anything with AE. My needs are very limited: I need to use AS for web navigation in order to create Flash-based websites.

Here's an example of what I'd like my websites to do: http://www.hellomonday.net/

Can anybody point me to Flash templates, demos, tutorials, AS libraries, websites, videos, classes, that focus on Flash navigation, with specific examples of real life websites? Or blocks of code where all I have to do is replace some lines with my own stuff? Or an AS library comparable to jQuery? I know this has to be doable. I don't know any JavaScript either, but I'm perfectly able to fulfill all my web design needs with jQuery.

Or, is there any way to look at the code of websites that I like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're a beginner to Flash and you want your site to be like an industry leader in Flash websites? Not to discourage you, but start on an easier project to begin with.

Comment: I'd start with this...http://gotoandlearn.com/ Simple tutorials for doing complex stuff (like Hello Monday does). ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not way to look at code on most websites that are created in flash. This is because flash files get compiled into .swf files which don't expose any of the source code.

You may want to check out these websites for tutorials:

http://www.flashkit.com

http://www.kirupa.com/

Or also if are wanting some pre-built flash components, check out this site:

http://activeden.net/

Answer (score 0):

I would lean more towards Flex that Flash itself, if, the site is more of an application than a presentation; ie its more data driven. You can embed and communicate with flash from within flex also.

It lends itself better to navigation thanks to [states](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/creating_states/) among other things.

If you want deep linking and SEO you may struggle. If this is your requirement then one option is seperate html pages with different flex / files on each. This will, to some extent, help if SEO / deeplinking is a requirement.

Silverlight 3 has a new navigation model which supports deep linking and works well. Its different tech completely however and it isn't the most adopted plug-in in the world.

Adobe flash docs are OK starting point but they are no MSDN. 
[Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB346GB346&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=flash+navigation+tutorials) has lots of tutorials, and the Linda training videos may not be a bad start either.

I would start small and learn the framework a little before considering the arch and navigation. To abstract that even more i would consider learning the core basics of programming also, if this isnt a strong point.

Hope this helps :)